# PHP: Prepared statements (newbie) getting this error

Tags: php, mysql, database, prepared-statement

I am a newbie to prepared statements and trying to get something simple to work.

This is my DB table:

```
`unblocker_users` (
  `uno` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_email` varchar(210) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pw_hash` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_confirmed` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_requests` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `today_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `accessed_today` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,)
```

and this is my function to insert some test data

```
function add_new_user($e_mail1)
    {
    require_once "db.php";
// ####### Below line is giving an error ########
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO unblocker_users VALUES ("",?, ?,0,0,?,0)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $e_mail1, $this->genRandomString(1),$this->today_date()); 

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close(); 
$done = $stmt->affected_rows;

return $done;
    }
```

As you can see above, i have marked the line that is giving me an error.
The error is`" Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in..."`

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line might be causing a problem

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO unblocker_users VALUES ("",?, ?,0,0,?,0)");
```

See you close and open the string again in the values, change `""` to `''` Thats all I could see from a quick glance.

Comment: All 3 answers were right but you were first so I picked yours as the correct answer. I hope thats ok wth you other guys.

Comment: cheers mate. Don't forget to accept an answer. I'd go with @KingCrunch -- haha you can change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have " with a double quoted string.  PHP thinks

`"INSERT INTO unblocker_users VALUES ("",?, ?,0,0,?,0)"`

is 2 strings:

`"INSERT INTO unblocker_users VALUES ("`

`",?, ?,0,0,?,0)"`

but doesn't what you want to do with them.

change the outside quotes to single quotes and it should work:

`'INSERT INTO unblocker_users VALUES ("",?, ?,0,0,?,0)'`

Answer (score 3):

```
"INSERT INTO unblocker_users VALUES ("",?, ?,0,0,?,0)"
```

In php if you want to use double quotes within double quotes, you must escape the inner ones

```
"INSERT INTO unblocker_users VALUES (\"\",?, ?,0,0,?,0)"
```

Or use single quotes as outer ...

```
'INSERT INTO unblocker_users VALUES ("",?, ?,0,0,?,0)'
```

... or inner quotes

```
"INSERT INTO unblocker_users VALUES ('',?, ?,0,0,?,0)"
```

As far as I know mySQL use single quotes anyway

Comment: HAHA! All 3 of you guys immediately got the problem :)   
  Just cant beat experience!

Comment: New problem though, "$done = $stmt->affected_rows; is not giving me anything but an error :( how do i get the affected rows or basically confirmation if the insert worked? (Have voted up all the answers as thanks)

Comment: Usually the PHP interpreter describes, where the problem occurs (the part you cut down from the error message above `unexpected XYZ in ...`). You can trust it ;)

Comment: @Ryan: Seems to be an other problem. Open a new question, if you can't solve it yourself, and describe the problem more detailed. The comments are not the right place for follow-up problems.